# How to change a HEAD request to a GET request with the redirection with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,json,make_response,Response,request,redirect,url_for
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,resources=r'/*')

@app.route('/operation',methods=['GET'])
def payload():
    return render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/',methods=['HEAD'])
def start():
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/operation',code=303)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port="8001",debug = True)
```

As I receive a HEAD request, I would want to redirect the request to a GET request and return an html page. The problem was that Flask adds automatically the method HEAD when GET is set alone in *methods* parameter (from documentation):

```
If GET is present in the list of methods and HEAD is not, HEAD is added automatically
```

Modifying the source code of Flask it's possible to avoid this behaviour, but when a client A makes a HEAD request to my server, it redirects that one to */operation* but maintaining the HEAD method also with a 303 or 302 status code for the redirection. Probably I didn't understand the logic of these codes (I've also read the relative RFC), but shouldn't the method change from HEAD to GET?

Thanks so much for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the `url_for` method. Your Code will then look like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,json,make_response,Response,request,redirect,url_for
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,resources=r'/*')

@app.route('/operation',methods=['GET'])
def payload():
    return render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/',methods=['HEAD'])
def start():
    return redirect(url_for('payload'),code=303)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port="8001",debug = True)
```